# Sage Pay Server Integration with .NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, opayo

How do we integrate SagePay with .NET MVC

When we try to use in MVC its returning vpsprotocol as 2.23 only instead of 3.00

Can someone let us know how to include the reference for the dll properly in .NET MVC

Answer (score 2):

Here is my example of implementation Sage Pay Server Integration and Protocol Guidelines 3.00 with MVC and .Net Core 2.2 
The part of code with "VPSProtocol", "3.00"

```
 [HttpPost("submited")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SubmitedPayment(PaymentDTO paymentDTO)
    {
        paymentDTO.Description = "Invoice Description";
        paymentDTO.VendorTxCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper();
        paymentDTO.NotificationURL = $"{_configuration["AppUrl"]}/Payment/RedirectURL";
        paymentDTO.Vendor = _configuration["Vendor"];
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var data = PostData(paymentDTO);
        var result = await client.PostAsync(_configuration["SagePayUrl"], new FormUrlEncodedContent(data));
        var contentResponse = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if (contentResponse.Contains("Status=OK"))
            return Redirect(await SaveSuccessResponseData(paymentDTO, contentResponse));
        ViewBag.StatusDetail = contentResponse;
        return View("Error");
    }
   private Dictionary<string, string> PostData(PaymentDTO paymentDTO)
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "VPSProtocol", "3.00" },
            { "TxType", "PAYMENT" },
            { "Vendor", _configuration["Vendor"] },
            { "Currency", paymentDTO.Currency },
            { "Amount", paymentDTO.Amount.ToString() },
            { "Description", paymentDTO.Description },
            { "VendorTxCode", paymentDTO.VendorTxCode },
            { "NotificationURL", paymentDTO.NotificationURL},
            { "BillingFirstnames", paymentDTO.BillingFirstnames },
            { "BillingSurname", paymentDTO.BillingSurname },
            { "BillingAddress1", paymentDTO.BillingAddress1 },
            { "BillingAddress2", paymentDTO.BillingAddress2 },
            { "BillingCity", paymentDTO.BillingCity },
            { "BillingPostCode", paymentDTO.BillingPostCode },
            { "BillingCountry", paymentDTO.BillingCountry },
            { "DeliveryFirstnames", paymentDTO.DeliveryFirstnames ?? paymentDTO.BillingFirstnames},
            { "DeliverySurname", paymentDTO.DeliverySurname ?? paymentDTO.BillingSurname},
            { "DeliveryAddress1", paymentDTO.DeliveryAddress1 ?? paymentDTO.BillingAddress1},
            { "DeliveryAddress2", paymentDTO.DeliveryAddress2 ?? paymentDTO.BillingAddress2},
            { "DeliveryCity", paymentDTO.DeliveryCity ?? paymentDTO.BillingCity},
            { "DeliveryPostCode", paymentDTO.DeliveryPostCode ?? paymentDTO.BillingPostCode},
            { "DeliveryCountry", paymentDTO.DeliveryCountry ?? paymentDTO.BillingCountry},
            { "BillingState", paymentDTO.BillingState },
            { "DeliveryState", paymentDTO.DeliveryState ?? paymentDTO.BillingState},
            { "CustomerEMail", paymentDTO.CustomerEMail}
        };
    }
```

The whole project is available on GitHub https://github.com/AleksandrChuikov/SagePay-ServerIntegration-MVC-.NET-Core-2.2